# Как группировать узлы XML в результатах запроса SELECT XMLElement в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Каким образом можно перевести данные таблицы в XML ?

Есть таблица:

```
-------------
ALLTAGS
-------------
TAGID | COUNT
-------------
1     | 2
2     | 5
3     | 4
-------------
```

Нужно получить XML такого вида:

```
<ALLSCOPES>
    <ResultTag>
        <Tag_ID>1</Tag_ID>
        <Tag_Count>2</Tag_Count>
    </ResultTag>
    <ResultTag>
        <Tag_ID>2</Tag_ID>
        <Tag_Count>5</Tag_Count>
    </ResultTag>
    <ResultTag>
        <Tag_ID>3</Tag_ID>
        <Tag_Count>4</Tag_Count>
    </ResultTag>
</ALLSCOPES>
```

Пробую сделать так:

```
SELECT  (XMLElement("ALLSCOPES",
            XMLElement("ResultTag",
                XMLElement("Tag_ID", t.TAG_ID),
                XMLElement("Tag_Count", t.TAGCOUNT)))
        ).GetStringVal() as ALLSCOPES
FROM ALLTAGS t;
```

но получаю 3 записи вида:

```
<ALLSCOPES>
    <ResultTag>
        <Tag_ID>1</Tag_ID>
        <Tag_Count>2</Tag_Count>
    </ResultTag>    
</ALLSCOPES>

<ALLSCOPES>     
        <ResultTag>
            <Tag_ID>2</Tag_ID>
            <Tag_Count>5</Tag_Count>
        </ResultTag>        
    </ALLSCOPES>
```

итд.

Как правильно решить мою задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не понимаю в oracle. Набираю в google запрос: `SELECT XMLElement`, открываю первую ссылку, смотрю [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#CHEJIFCD) и вижу:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Department", XMLAgg(XMLElement("Employee",
                                              e.job_id||' '||e.last_name)
                                   ORDER BY e.last_name))
  AS "Dept_list"     
  FROM hr.employees e
  WHERE e.department_id = 30 OR e.department_id = 40;
```

должен давать результат:

```
Dept_list
------------------
<Department>
  <Employee>PU_CLERK Baida</Employee>
  <Employee>PU_CLERK Colmenares</Employee>
  <Employee>PU_CLERK Himuro</Employee>
  <Employee>PU_CLERK Khoo</Employee>
  <Employee>HR_REP Mavris</Employee>
  <Employee>PU_MAN Raphaely</Employee>
  <Employee>PU_CLERK Tobias</Employee>
</Department>
```

Похоже? Похоже. Пробуем приспособить к вашему запросу:

```
SELECT  (XMLElement("ALLSCOPES",
        XMLAgg(XMLElement("ResultTag",
            XMLElement("Tag_ID", t.TAG_ID),
            XMLElement("Tag_Count", t.TAGCOUNT))))
    ).GetStringVal() as ALLSCOPES
  FROM ALLTAGS t;
```

Попробуете?

Comment: Проверил за ТС, да, работает :)